# What's a better way to load a file using boto? (getting filename too long error)

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-s3, boto, amazon-sagemaker

So I'm trying to use `tf.contrib.learn.preprocessing.VocabularyProcessor.restore()` to restore a vocabulary file from an S3 bucket. First, I tried to get the path name to the bucket to use in `.restore()` and I kept getting 'object doesn't exist' error. Afterwards, upon further research, I found a method people use to load text files and JSON files and applied the same method here:

```
obj = s3.Object(BUCKET_NAME, KEY).get()['Body'].read()
vocab_processor = tf.contrib.learn.preprocessing.VocabularyProcessor.restore(obj)
```

This worked for a while until the contents of file increased and eventually got a 'File name too long' error. Is there a better way to load and restore a file from an S3 bucket?

By the way, I tested this out locally on my machine and it works perfectly fine since there it just needs to take the path to the file, not the entire contents of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you’re passing in the actual contents of the file as the file name?

I think you’ll need to download the object from S3 to a tmp file and pass the path to that file into restore.

Try using the method here: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.download_file

Update:
I went through the code here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/preprocessing/text.py and it looks like this just saves a pickle so you can really easily just import pickle and call the following:

```
import pickle
obj = s3.Object(BUCKET_NAME, KEY).get()['Body']
vocab_processor = pickle.loads(obj.read())
```

Hopefully that works?

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing something similar right now. Here, I have to take care of deleting the file and I found that a little clunky. I was hoping for a more elegant solution like how file input/output works with a local system. I guess that's not possible with S3 buckets. However, this solution works fine. Thanks!

Comment: added an update about using pickle to load the file from the string. If you're looking for additional optimizations you could probably use cPickle if you're on python2, not needed on 3.

Comment: Fantastic! While the other solution worked, this was exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate the help!